# Error in BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

Hello

I have the following issue, i'm trying to retrieve the image from openweathermap.com, I have a service that access to the the page and retrieve the image as a byte array, I'm using the same service in an IOS app and work fine so I know that the service is working properly.

Service Code:

```
public byte[] GetWeatherIcon(string iconDesc)
    {
        byte[] result;
        string url = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconDesc + ".png";
        Image image = RequestImage_Get(url, null, null, null);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            result = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In my Android application I'm executing the following code to access the service:

```
String urlIcon = SERVICEURL + "/GetWeatherIcon/" + weather.getWeather().get(0).getIcon();
InputStream iconStream = ExecuteRequestService(urlIcon);
BufferedReader rdIcon = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iconStream));
String jsonIcon = rdIcon.readLine();
JSONObject objIcon = new JSONObject(jsonIcon);
byte[] bytes = objIcon.getString("GetWeatherIconResult").getBytes("UTF-8");
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);
weather.setImage(bmp);
```

The method ExecuteRequestService code's is:

```
protected InputStream ExecuteRequestService(String url) throws Exception{
    try{
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            return conn.getInputStream();
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("An error occurred accessing MiOS server");
    }
}
```

The error that i'm getting is: D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

I was reading a few post with the same exception but all of them are related with BitmapFactory.decodeStream but in my case is different as you can see but i can't find the problem, that's why i need your help

Here is an example of the url that I'm running so you can see the Json:

[Url running to get Json](https://rapidweb3000.com/RapidSentry/MiOSService.svc/GetWeatherIcon/02d)

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for all your help, after break my neurons y found a good solution for this:

As you can see the structure of the json I was getting the byte array as String this is the code with the solution:

```
String urlIcon = SERVICEURL + "/GetWeatherIcon/" + weather.getWeather().get(0).getIcon();
InputStream iconStream = ExecuteRequestService(urlIcon);
BufferedReader rdIcon = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iconStream));
String jsonIcon = rdIcon.readLine();
JSONObject objIcon = new JSONObject(jsonIcon);
JSONArray jsonArray = objIcon.getJSONArray("GetWeatherIconResult");
byte[] bytes = new byte[jsonArray.length()];
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
   bytes[i] = (byte) jsonArray.getLong(i);
}
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
weather.setImage(bmp);
```

I hope this help a few more like me.

Answer (score 0):

`SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` ? You mean `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() returns null` ? Same cause as allways. Not enough memory. What's the size of the byte array? What's the size of the picture?

Comment: Thank you @greenapps the `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` is the message that i'm getting in the android monitor. the image is just a weather icon, it can't be out of memory, actually if you clic on the url you could see the byte array.

Comment: Hmm i saw the result of that url. That is just text. Maybe json text? But not the bytes of an icon. So your `bytes[]` do not contain the bytes of an icon. You have to decode what you received differend then you do now.

Comment: What you should do instead is looping through all those decimal values and put them in a byte array.

Comment: For instance the first decimal value of 137 becomes three bytes with the String:getBytes() method. But you should put the value 137 in the first byte of your byte array.

Comment: I think you are right, i just going to do some test and i come back to you with the results, thanks

Comment: If it is really an icon -not a jpg or png- then i would not wonder if BitmapFactory could not handle your decoded byte array. Save it to file then and inspect it with the gallery app.

Comment: It is a png image, i said icon but sorry about that, one question how can i add to a byte array the decimal because it is a string? Thank you for your help

Comment: I can't find the way to get this work i made the following changes but it is not working yet: `String[] jsonArray = jsonIcon.split(":");
            String bytesAr = jsonArray[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            byte[] bytes = android.util.Base64.decode(bytesAr, 0);`

Comment: String value = "137";  bytes[0] = Integer.valueOf(value);

Comment: I did this: `byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesQ.length];
            for(int i=0; i<bytesQ.length; i++){
                bytes[i] = Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]);
            }` but there is compilation error: required bytes no Int

Comment: You should care that you do a json extraction so you end up with a string like String thevalues = "137,78,23,67";  String values [] = thevalues.split(","); Then loop through the values and place them in successive bytes of your array.

Comment: What is bytesQ? And if you have a compilation error you should tell on which code line.

Comment: thank you so much, I try to do your suggestions: ` String[] bytesQ = bytesAr.split(",");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesQ.length];
            for(int i=0; i<bytesQ.length; i++){
                bytes[i] = Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]);
            }` but I got a compile error incompatible types, the error is in this line: `bytes[i] = Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]);`

Comment: Show what bytesAr is and the content. byterAr should be equal like String thevalues that i proposed. What is bytersQ? You still did not tell.

Comment: the problem is that android studio marks as an error the line: `bytes[i] = Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]);` because there is incompatible types, I can't assign Integer to byte because it is byte what it is expected

Comment: Then cast the integer to byte. bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]); And why are you so unfriendly nkt to tell what bytesQ is?

Comment: other error: Inconvertible types, can't convert Integer to byte

Comment: sorry but I don't want to be unfriendly is that i'm not good with english, `String[] bytesQ = bytesAr.split(",");` it is a string array like = "137,80,78,71,13..."

Comment: Try like this: int value = Integer.valueOf(bytesQ[i]); bytes[i] =(byte)value;

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @greenapps, that solve the compile error i'm testing right now to what happen

Comment: thank you very and i'm sorry for being bothering you for so long but it doesn't work, i think i'm going to change the service because in the way that you suggested don't fire any exception but don't decode the byte array.

Comment: Save the array to file and inspect.

Comment: Please keep that url in the air. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: Well it does work. Exactly as i described how it should be done. And equal to the one you posted a few comments above.

Answer (score 0):

As private variable in your AsyncTask class:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
```

In doinbackground:

```
JSONObject objIcon = new JSONObject(jsonIcon);

String thevalues = objIcon.get("GetWeatherIconResult").toString();

thevalues = thevalues.replace("[", "");
thevalues = thevalues.replace("]", "");

result = thevalues;

String values[] = thevalues.split(",");

byte bytes[] = new byte [values.length];

int nr = -1;    
while (++nr < values.length)
    {
    int value = Integer.valueOf(values[nr]);
    bytes[nr] = (byte)value;    
    }

bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

In onPostExecute:

```
if ( bmp != null )
        {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById ( R.id.imageView);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time I appreciate a lot, yesterday in the night was a cold mind I start to thinking in this deal and i got a solution, I'm going to publish because i think it is good solution, but I want to thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

simply use below code

```
byte[] img = Base64.decode(Service.GetImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
                    imageid.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bitmap));
```